# VBA - Import namespaces?

Tags: vba, namespaces, module

Is it possible to import namespaces in VBA? I'm writing Word macros and I want to put all functions inside Modules or Classes. But once I do that I see that I cannot reach the controls in the VBA form easily. I have to include the name of the form first, then access the control within that one. I can't just go

```
TextBox1.Caption
```

I have to go

```
Form1.TextBox1.Caption
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You shouldn't be coupling your classes/modules so tightly.** A worker module shouldn't require knowledge of the `Form1` class, because then it can't be used separately in another project.

Instead, you probably want to pass the function in your helper class an *argument* on which it performs work, and then returns the result (if necessary). As a completely useless, trivial example:

```
Public Sub SetLabelText(ByVal lbl As Label, ByVal caption As String)
    lbl.Caption = caption
End Sub
```

And you would call it from within the form class, like so:

```
MyHelpers.SetLabelText(Label1, "New Label Caption")
```

That way, you can use the functions in your helper class from *any* form.

---

But, as far as your actual question, no. VBA doesn't have any concept of "namespaces". The best you can do is the `With` statement, but having to do this frequently is more likely an indication of a design flaw, as I discussed above.