# C# COM Object VBA function or interface marked as restricted or the function uses an automation type not supported

Tags: c#, vba, com, ms-word

I have the following C# COM Object :

```
[ComVisible(true), GuidAttribute("FD87D0EA-1D00-4189-801A-987D5F8ABD2C")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IRegistration
{
    string RegisterForm(string server, string database, string username, string password, string catalogId, string date, string AxyaContextFile);
    void RegisterFormAcknowledge(string server, string database, string username, string password, long formId, bool isPrinted, string message);
}
```

When I call the method RegisterFormAcknowledge from Word 200, I get the following compilation exception :
function or interface marked as restricted or the function uses an automation type not supported

Here is the Word macro code

```
    Set printer = New MyCOMObject.Registration
    printer.RegisterFormAcknowledge "test", "test", "test", "test", 12345, False, "CatalogWordTemplate Not Found"
```

Does anyone has an idea why ? Long type are not supported by VB6 ?
The first method RegisterForm is working well.

Comment: public void RegisterFormAcknowledge(string server, string database, string username, string password, long formId, bool isPrinted, string message)

Comment: I just changed the parameter "long formId" into "int formId" and it works. Does anyone knows why ?

Comment: Yes, `long` is a signed **64-bit** integer, which is not automation-compatible.  On the other hand, `int` is a signed **32-bit** integer, which is automation-compatible.

Comment: Then, if I want to pass a value bigger than int.Max, I should pass it by string, and parse it in the C# code ?

Comment: It depends.  If it's not signed, you can use `uint` and the limit is roughly the double of `Int32.MaxValue`, i.e. `UInt32.MaxValue`.

Comment: If I want to pass the value 372,036,854,775,807 I must pass it as string ? Or is it another DataType more appropriated ?

Comment: For that value, you can use a `double`, as it can represent faithfully integers up to 53 bits.  For larger integers, yes, you'll have to use `string`.  Or an array of bytes, but if this is not "hot" code, it's more trouble without reason.

Comment: I should probably write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
```

That's a mistake, VB6 and VBA require a dispatch interface.  Boilerplate is to use ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsAutoDual so that the client code can use both early and late-binding.  You almost surely need to fix the [ClassInterface] attribute on the class that implements this interface as well, given that you could actually make calls, use ClassInterfaceType.None

Using *long* as an argument type isn't going to fly, it is not a type supported in VB6.  VB1 started life as a 16-bit tool so Integer is 16-bits and Long is 32-bits.  No type for 64-bit integrals.  Use *int* if a VB6 Long was intended.  If not then you'll need to consider Double, gets you up to 15 digits, or String.

Comment: +1 for picking up on the attribute. I love reading [your answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615044/early-binding-of-a-c-sharp-com-library-in-vba)

Comment: Not to muck the waters up, but 64bit versions of Office do have a `LongLong` type which *is* a 64 bit integer.

Answer (score 2):

C#'s [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) is a signed **64-bit** integer, which is not [automation-compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237562.aspx). On the other hand, C#'s [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) is a signed **32-bit** integer, which is automation-compatible.

You asked about large integers, such as 372036854775807.

This one in particular needs 49 bits to represent.  C#'s [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) is a standard [double float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which can represent integers that require up to 53 bits.

There's also C#'s [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx), which maps to e.g. VBA's `Decimal` (inside a `VARIANT`).  If you wish, you can marshal it as e.g. VBA's `Currency`, a signed 64-bit integer, with the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)]` attribute before the argument definition.

For larger values, you should probably be better off using a `string`.  That is, if you can actually deal with them in VBA.